# Setting view controller for titleView of UINavigationItem

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I am creating a view controller that is pushed to the `UINavigationController`. I need a customized navigation bar, therefore I have overridden `navigationItem` method of my view controller. In a `titleView` (property of `UINavigationItem`) I need a custom view that holds two buttons. Question: how to apply view controller for those two buttons?

View containing two buttons is defined in `CustomTitleViewController.xib`, whereas its view controller is defined in `CustomTitleViewController` class.

This is my way of returning the navigation item (`MainViewController.m`):

```
- (UINavigationItem *)navigationItem
{
    UINavigationItem *navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];

    UIViewController *customTitleViewController =
        [[CustomTitleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomTitleViewController"
                                                    bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    navItem.titleView = [customTitleViewController view];

    return navItem;
}
```

The view is shown on the navigation bar, as expected. However, tapping the button crashes the application (`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`).

Error message: `message sent to deallocated instance 0x6e53850`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to retain pointer to viewController as well as to its view. Just create strong property on your UINavigation controller subclass. Coz what you are doing here is instantiating new controller each time navigation item is called and realising it at the end of the function. Here is a very quick crude fix:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/y6ltdyj951ioncd/Navigating.zip
be sure not to reinstantiate VC all the time and keep pointer to it.
Hope this helped.

Comment: Can you please add what was on that zip here so even we can understand the code? Thanks.